# Understanding HTML code for a specific web page

Tags: html, html-parsing

I am trying to see the code the following URL - http://www.chilis.com/EN/Pages/menuitem.aspx

I am seeing some weird things on the page that I cannot understand. I was hoping some one could explain it to me.

1. The actual menu items I see in the browser are no where to be found in the source code. The page does not look like its using any ajax style calls.
2. There is a piece of base64 blob in there. I decoded it and its still results in base64 encoded bytes. Not sure what that is and why its even there in the source page.

Thanks for any help.

P

Comment: The menu items are in the source code, underneath `ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv`

Comment: @Pekka웃 -- I don't see the menu items. Are they loaded as part of some other URL?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firebug or similar and look at the network panel and watch the downloaded files carefully, you will see that a file called Navigator.txt gets fetched which contains the left side menu (Appetizersn & Flatbreads, etc.) in JSON format.

Going after this and figuring out what part of the site is actually loading this Navigator.txt should give you a hint about how the menu is being constructed exactly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Loading content of menu via ajax

As CodeTwice pointed out [the file Navigator.txt](http://www.chilis.com/EN/MenuLibrary/R.001.005.0000/Navigator.txt) is beeing loaded via ajax (xhr) to get the data.

[image: Network tab filtered for XHR calls]

If you add a breakpoint into chrome devtools for the URL of Navigator.txt you can see which javascript file and which method is repsonsible for loading the menu-data.

[image: Add xhr breakpoint for url]

[image: see debugger pausing at breakpoint]

If you use chrome devtools it is easier to analyze the source code:

- an [intro to chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)
- a [short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI) by Paul Irish
- a [longer video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaneWEqNcpE) one by Ilya Grigorik

#### Base64 could you mean the Viewstate?

Scrolling through the source code i can only find the viewstate that looks like a base64 encoded string. Can you clarify which part you mean?

#### Are your questions answered?

To [paraphrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase) your questions:

- The menu items are not in the source code. Does the page load them via ajax? Yes it does.
- What is the base64 blob in the code? If you talk about the [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) this is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form across postbacks. If you [google viewstate](http://www.google.com/search?setmkt=de-DE&q=what%20is%20aspx%20viewstate) you can find many articles that describe it.

Does this answer your questions? If it is not the case than please feel free to add more details to your question.